# Datatable horizontal scroll issue

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

Downloaded the new Datatable from [here](http://datatables.net), its working fine but the problem is related to scrolling.

I have got the latest version of java script but when i scroll horizontally there is a log i can

observe in moment between the body of table and title. i'm not sure why its happening.

This problem comes when i deploy to IIS web server.

Another problem what i found in IIS server is there is mismatch in alignment between search label and

search box in datatable.

Comment: It could be you have a lot of data in table, or your browser is slow. Try setting opacity to .01 temporary, until the table is created. The list of events is [here](http://datatables.net/reference/event/).

Comment: Why don't you report this issue to the [DataTables GitHub Repo](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues)?

Answer (score 0):

The headers are actually a separate HTML table and their position relative to the data columns is maintained by javascript.

If you view the source of your page you can see the headers table is in the `dataTables_scrollHead` element and the data is in in a table in the `dataTables_scrollBody` element. As you scroll horizontally in the body of the datatable, the headers are scrolled via javascript probably by listening to the `scroll` event and updating the scroll position of the headers.

I doubt there is a way to make this smoother as the responsiveness is going to depend a lot on the client.

Comment: I do not see headers are scrolled via Javascript. Think JS only adds cell widths. I am looking at [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html).

Comment: AFAIK that was true 2 years ago when I answered this question; I'm not sure about now, I haven't used datatables much since then

Comment: Heh, haven't seen the question is so old. Cheers